# RxJava to live data error Handling

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

So, in my android project I am using RxJava in the repository layer then I convert it to live data in the view Model, but I am having an exception when my stream emits an error. It has something to do with this remark from the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams.html#fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher%3CT%3E)):

> **fromPublisher**
>
> [`LiveData<T>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html) `fromPublisher (Publisher<T> publisher)`
>
> Creates an Observable [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html) stream from a `ReactiveStreams` publisher.
>
> When the `LiveData` becomes active, it subscribes to the emissions from the Publisher.
>
> When the `LiveData` becomes inactive, the subscription is cleared. `LiveData` holds the last value emitted by the Publisher when the `LiveData` was active.
>
> Therefore, in the case of a hot RxJava Observable, when a new `LiveData` [`Observer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Observer.html) is added, it will automatically notify with the last value held in `LiveData`, which might not be the last value emitted by the Publisher.
>
> Note that `LiveData` does NOT handle errors and it expects that errors are treated as states in the data that's held. In case of an error being emitted by the publisher, an error will be propagated to the main thread and the app will crash.

How can I handle the stream error?
PS: I am using a Kotlin extension to convert to Live data

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.toLiveData(backPressureStrategy: BackpressureStrategy =
                                                BackpressureStrategy.LATEST) :  LiveData<T> {
Log.d("RxJava",this.toString())
return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(this.toFlowable(backPressureStrategy))
```

Answer (score 3):

As a newbie, i'm not sure about this solution. But it works. So, if it's bad, please comment to say why and provide an alternative.

Use this :

```
data class DataWithStates<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val states: Throwable? = null
)
```

Sample for ViewModel :

```
fun getUsers(): LiveData<DataWithStates<List<User>>> {
    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
        userRepository
            .getAll()
            .map { lstUser -> DataWithStates(lstUser) }
            .onErrorReturn { ex -> DataWithStates(states = ex) }
            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST))
}
```

Maybe it's better to move .map and .onErrorReturn in the repository.

Edit : alternatively, you can use a lambda to listen for error.

```
fun getUsers(onError: () -> Unit = {}): LiveData<List<User>> {
    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
        userRepository
            .getAll()
            .doOnError { onError() }
            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your are using live data (android architecure components).Better to use its predefined oberserver (Which is in architecutural components).Otherwise fully u need to use RX android clases only