# LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher crash application when not internet connection

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

```
W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.rawg.io": No address associated with hostname
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:214)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:186)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:45)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10838)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10838)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromObservable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromObservable.java:29)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12978)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnBackpressureLatest.subscribeActual(FlowableOnBackpressureLatest.java:32)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12978)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(FlowableDoOnEach.java:50)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12978)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12924)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:200)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
        ... 43 more
```

When application have connection with internet working good but when i have no internet connection my application crash. I want to handle this Exception but anything what i tried not helped  :/ . I tried too check if source is not null . I am using Dagger 2 , Retrofit 2, RxJava, viewModel .

```
  class VideoViewModel : ViewModel {

    private val authApi: AuthApi

    private val games: MediatorLiveData<TopGames> = MediatorLiveData<TopGames>() 

    @Inject
    constructor(authApis: AuthApi) {

        authApi = authApis
    }


    fun authenticateWithId(dates: String) {
        val source: LiveData<TopGames> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
            authApi.getTopGames(dates, "-added").doOnError { t-> print("${t.printStackTrace()}  doOnError") }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        )
        games.addSource<TopGames>(source, object : androidx.lifecycle.Observer<TopGames?> {

            override fun onChanged(t: TopGames?) {
                //   Log.d("TAG", "VideoonChanged: $t")
                games.value = t
                games.removeSource(source)
            }
        })
    }



    fun observeGaneInfo(): LiveData<TopGames?>? {
        return games
    }
}
```

Other class

```
interface AuthApi {
 
    @GET("/api/games")
    fun getTopGames(
        @Query("dates") dates: String,
        @Query("ordering") ordering: String
    ): Flowable<TopGames>
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to add `onErrorReturn` or some other error handling in the Rx chain.  Currently there is no error handling, so on a valid error that is not handed it will crash. Consider mapping to a `Result<TopGames>` class, that will allow errors down the "happy path" and you can evaluate in the observer to give the right UI feedback to the user if unsuccessful.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208618/how-to-handle-error-states-with-livedata

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

create data class on State

```
data class DataWithStates<T>(
        val data: T? = null,
        val states: Throwable? = null
    )
```

and in my live data i change  val source: LiveData to  LiveData<DataWithStates>  and work perfectly

```
  fun authenticateWithId(dates: String) {
        val source: LiveData<DataWithStates<TopGames>> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
            authApi.getTopGames(dates, "-added").map { lstUser -> DataWithStates(lstUser) }.onErrorReturn { ex -> DataWithStates(states = ex) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        )

        games.addSource<DataWithStates<TopGames>>(source, object : androidx.lifecycle.Observer<DataWithStates<TopGames>> {

            override fun onChanged(t: DataWithStates<TopGames>) {
                //   Log.d("TAG", "VideoonChanged: $t")
                games.value = t.data
                games.removeSource(source)
            }
        })
    }
```

helpful Link
[RxJava to live data error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51152115/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no error handling in your rx chain. So you might to want to do something like this.

```
        val source: LiveData<TopGames> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
        authApi.getTopGames(dates, "-added")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                {
                    games.value = it
                },
                {
                    // error handling goes here
                }
            )
        )
```

You can have separate `LiveData` for your error messages, but the more cleaner approach would be to create `State` class, as mentioned in other replies, so you only have the single source of view state updates.

Also please note that the `Disposable` return from `subscribe` method is better to be disposed on `ViewModel's` `onCleared` method.